# python unix timestamp is not as UTC on Pycharm console

Tags: python, time, pycharm

Not sure what the problem is here.

I use `time.time()` and I get `1492374538`, which translated is Sunday 16th April 2017 01:28:58 PM; this is via the Pycharm python console.
Although the local time is actually 8:28.58 PM

Another application printing out Unix time, on the same machine, is giving me a different number, that translate in Sunday 16th April 2017 08:28.58 PM, which is the correct time.

Why is Python not returning the same Unix time, and instead returning me the time off by 7 hours? My understanding was that Unix time is done on purpose so any machine anywhere is returning the same date.

Comment: That timestamp is  Sunday 16th April 2017 08:28.58 PM UTC.  So Python thinks you timezone is UTC....

Comment: What OS are you using and what timezone does it think it is?

Comment: The time on the clock of my computer was 8:28 PM; regional settings say PST timezone; the OS is OSX 10.11
I just did run time.time() in console and it return the correct time, so the issue seems to be only on pycharm python console

Comment: Pycharm console time.time() just gave me a reasonable time, but I am on windows.